# How to get multiple strings between two other strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find all values between `{{` and `}}` that start with a `$` followed by `[\w.]+` but doesn't start with a number. This works in getting the value, however, it only gets the last item. What I am looking for, is a list of these items, so in this example I would like my array to contain (based off the example):

```
['{{I\'m $name and I am $age years old}}', '$name', '$age']
```

When executed, `$name` is not included in this array as seen here:

```js
let result = '$welcome: {{I\'m $name and I am $age years old}}'.match(/\{\{.*(\$(?!\d|\.)[\w.]+).*\}\}/)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Try `\$[.\w]+(?=[^{}]*})`. Or match that block first then run another regex on it.

Comment: This seems to be working https://regex101.com/r/GUcHxt/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex:

```
\$[.\w]+(?=[^{}]*})
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/8I1nNd/1)

This doesn't really match between `{{` and `}}` but it guarantees that it wouldn't find a match which is outside of braces. It assumes that single, unbalanced braces do not occur in input string.

Another approach  would be matching an entire `{{...}}` block then looking for `\$[\w.]+` but if you need to replace them in original input string this wouldn't be an easy option.

Comment: I am trying your second method, however, `/\$(?!(\d|\.))[.\w]+/` is only getting `$name` and not `$age`

Comment: Oops nope I didn't that fixes it!